# How to troubleshoot AWS Config remediations issues?

Tags: amazon-web-services, debugging, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-config, aws-ssm

I'm trying to develop custom remediations using SSM documents.

In some cases, when it goes wrong I can check it in the System Manager -> Automation console and see what's wrong with the code.

But there are these situations where I cannot see anything, and I'm currently stuck trying to fix this because I have no visibility on the actual issue.

So basically, the only thing I can see is this error: "Action execution failed"
[image: screenshot_anonymized.png]

Then when I look for it I can't find anything on the issue anywhere (System Manager, Cloudwatch, Config, etc...)

Does anyone know what this issue is? And/or a neat little trick to debug this?

For those who think it might be relevant to know the deployment stack for these remediations, it's: Terragrunt, terraform, SSM document in YAML with the code for two steps inside it using python.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the remediation execution status using following AWS CLI command:

```
aws configservice describe-remediation-execution-status \
     --config-rule-name <YOUR_RULE_NAME>
```

You should get JSON representation of execution, including State and StepDetails and ErrorMessage.

Be aware that Config may show that action execution failed, but Systems Manager Automation execution could show that step or the action was successfully completed.